# Getting value from variable causing a extra line

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help with HTML formatting. I am using bootstrap to build a page .If I hard code the value it appears fine but as soon as I pull the value as variable it the format becomes bad.

The code is :--

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-blue"><i class="fa fa-certificate"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Total</span>
              <span class="info-box-number"></span>
              <p id="total"></p>
            </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
          </div><!-- /.info-box -->
        </div><!-- /.col -->
       <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-green"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Authorized</span>
              <span class="info-box-number">19876</span>
            </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
          </div><!-- /.info-box -->
        </div><!-- /.col -->
```

Here is how it is getting changed.
[image]

There is an extra blank row getting added.

Can someone help me on it ?

Regards.

Comment: You are using P in first box '<p id="total"></p>'. P is a block level element that is causing it

Comment: Are you sure the variable contain only the number and not any leading and trailing whitespace with it?

Comment: Yes. The variable is having only one value . How to fix the block level element from creating a new space .

Comment: You can use span  tag for the same. It will be great if you post the relative CSS as well for the HTML.

Comment: It is using AdminLTE.css and bootstrap.css .. How to use the span tag instead of P

Comment: Thanks a lot CodeRemeos ... Span fixed the issue .. You rock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CodeRomeos suggestion I was able to fix it .

```
<span class="info-box-number"><span id="total"></span></span>
```